# taking full advantage of jquery 1.4 feature detection

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am specifically trying to target IE 6/7/8 and PREVENT those versions from recognizing the fadeIN effect in my javascript file.

Can anyone please help me implement this?

http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek

I had a snippet that looked like this to start with, but I dont know where to add it:

```
var FADE_TIME = 500; if(!($.support.opacity)) { FADE_TIME = 0}

$('element').fadeOut(FADE_TIME)
```

Comment: `var FADE_TIME = $.support.opacity ? 500 : 0;`

Comment: I tried adding this variable at the top of my dynamicpage.js file.  it didn't effect IE at all? :(

Answer (score 0):

first, put all of your content in a div element, and in a style sheet, set that element's opacity to 0. Then, with javascript, if the user's browser isn't IE, fade in, other wise just set it's opacity to 1. you could put it in document.ready or document.onload.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')==-1)
        //if we are not using IE
    $('element').fadeIn(500);
        //fade out
else
    $('element').css('opacity', '1')
        //set opacity to 0 if we are using IE
```

If you want to base it off fadeIn actually working, instead of being based directly of if the browser is IE, then just replace `navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')==-1` with `$.support.opacity` (`$.support.opacity` is a better idea).

Comment: ok can someone just post the entire thing from <script> to </script> please?